# Checkboxes in Jupyter markdown get disabled

Tags: jupyter-notebook, markdown

In Jupyter, when I create a markdown cell containing a checkbox, Jupyter will make that checkbox be disabled (i.e. add the `disabled` attribute). How can I have my checkboxes be enabled?

It happens whether I use markdown syntax

```
- [ ] MyCheckbox
```

or if I use plain html

```
<div>
<input type="checkbox" id="c1"/>
<label for="c1">MyCheckbox</label>
</div>
```

I'm looking for a solution that DOESN'T involve ipywidgets. (I want to create a notebook that will have clickable buttons labelled "Show me the answer", and I should be able to use css to make the answer displayed when the button is checked. I want to distribute the notebook, and I have no control over what extensions the user might have enabled. The user might not have ipywidgets / widgetsnbextension installed.)

I'm running Jupyter notebook version 6.5.2.

Comment: If you use [JupyterLite](https://jupyterlite.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) to share the notebook you can control what users have because it would be launched from a site you control, and ipywidgets works in JupyterLite. (See [the 'Build your own JupyterLite'](https://jupyterlite.readthedocs.io/en/stable/#build-your-own-jupyterlite) section there.) Otherwise, I don't see a lot of your ideas working for users running Jupyter Notebook 7+ and JupyterLab without making an extension, since as you state you have no control over what they have.